# Not able to render graph in angular from Neo4j by using Neovis.js

Tags: angularjs, angular, neo4j

I`m new to Neo4j and I'm trying to visualize Neo4j graph in angular component by using Neovis.js library .It also not showing any error in console and also not rendering anything on screen .Here is my code in component.ts file

```
Init() {

  let config = {
      container_id: "viz",
      server_url: "bolt://localhost:7687",
      server_user: "neo4j",
      server_password: "",
      labels: {
        //"Character": "name",
        "Character": {
          "caption": "name",
          "size": "pagerank",
          "community": "community"
          //"sizeCypher": "MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = {id} MATCH (n)-[r]-() RETURN sum(r.weight) AS c"
        }
      },
      relationships: {
        "INTERACTS": {
          "thickness": "weight",
          "caption": false
        }
      },
      initial_cypher: "Match (n) return (n)"
    };
  var viz = new NeoVis(config);
  viz.render();
}
```

Html Code:-

```
<head (load)="Init()">
  <title>Neovis.js Simple Example</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
      font: 16pt arial;
    }

    #viz {
      width: 900px;
      height: 700px;
      border: 1px solid lightgray;
      font: 22pt arial;
    }

  </style>
</head>
```

Comment: server_password is blank?

Comment: missing a container with `<div id="viz"></div>` ?